# Use admin$ share but list files in C:\

Tags: powershell, networking, share

I can only be sure that the share admin$ exist and the user has rights to the the admin$ share.  I can not use the C$ because the permission can be changed.  The admin$ share starts in C:\windows.  How can I list the files on the C:\ drive starting with Admin$?

"localhost" is only used to test with.  Localhost will be replaced with a server name in the final version.

Failed attempts.

```
#list the files in c:\windows
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\localhost\ADMIN$'

# path does not exist.
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\localhost\ADMIN$\C:\'

# tried back up ..\ but it still list the C:\windows
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\localhost\ADMIN$\..\'

# share to share. path does exist.
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\localhost\ADMIN$\C$'
```

Is is possible to read the C:\ using admin$ as a starting point?

Comment: the _entire point_ of a share is that you only have access to that part of the dir tree. [*grin*] so ... no, there is no way to do that directly. however, you can _create_ a connection and use an account that has perms to use that. take a look at `Get-Help New-PSDrive -Parameter Cred*` for one such idea.

Comment: Agree with @Lee_Dailey if someone shared from a specific point, it's obviously not the intent to allow access to points before it.